# Windows 7 DVD not booting

Tags: windows-7, boot

I am trying to reinstall Windows 7 but the DVD does not boot. It stops and show me only a blue background.

Previously I had Windows XP.

I tried using a USB stick but I've gotten the same thing.  The DVD boots on any other machines.

Answer (score 0):

There really are many reasons that can cause that problem. First you should check your system for the hardware requirements of Windows 7. And then say that, until what step of installing you can proceed.

Comment: My system has all the hardware requirements for win7. If i restart my PC and boot it from there it just loads up the necessary files i cannot even proceed to step 1. If i run it from My Computer it will run but i won`t be able to partition my drive

Comment: 1- Is it first time to installing Windows 7 on that system? 2- Doesn't have your system any problem if you install XP on it? And what has been wrote on that blue screen?

Comment: Yes it was the first time installing win7. I tried to install XP again but it gave me a "textsetup.sif" error and could not install it. It`s this screen http://www.buttonclicker.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/windows-7-build-7057-welcome-screen1-300x225.png but without any text on it.

Comment: About the "textsetup.sif" you can read this; http://www.techrepublic.com/forums/questions/win-xp-cannnot-boot-error-message-coming/. Sometimes even if the DVD and the machine are working good but it takes more time in some steps of installation to proceed. though your problem seems to be a bit deeper but try to wait a while and see what happens on that blue screen.

Comment: I'm very glad that could help someone. Nice time.